# componentWillRecieveProps doesnt cause render

Tags: reactjs, render

I've made a chat app that uses redux and MongoDB to store the chat,
when me and my friend log in to the website and write a message it comes from the redux to this function:

```
 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.chat.chat) {
      this.setState({ chat: nextProps.chat.chat });
    }
  }
```

If I write the message on my end, I get a re-render due to setState and I can see the DOM manipulation, but my friend has to refresh the page to see what I wrote,
how can I make the page render on his page aswel?

To make my question clear, how can I check if the dataBase updated and cause a re-render?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to utilize something like subscriptions or sockets to make this work. You can think of sockets as an open connection between you/your friend  (client) and the server. When you send a message, your socket library would emit an event telling all the connection clients that a message was sent and likely send down the new message as a payload.

https://itnext.io/building-a-node-js-websocket-chat-app-with-socket-io-and-react-473a0686d1e1 - that article should be enough to point you in the right direction.